# Django TimeStamp inconsistency

Tags: django, postgresql, fullcalendar, unix-timestamp

I'm working on a scheduling web application for work and am having a very weird problem. The application uses Django and FullCalendar. In the application users can create an event in FullCalendar and the start and end time get stored as a DateTime field in a PostgreSQL database. When the events are returned to the calendar I use a Django DateTag to convert the times to a UnixTimestamp. Everything works perfectly except that the timestamp will randomly be returned one hour early for all events. About every few times I access the page the timestamp will be off by one hour.

Has anyone else experienced a similar problem and been able to find a fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a live server perhaps you need to check the .conf files for timestamp settings?

For example you may find that at `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

And add the following line `setenv TZ America/<Timezone>`

Comment: This fixed the problem. Thank you! It's weird that the time would be randomly be different each time I refreshed but adding this to httpd.conf did fix the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Suspiciously sounds like a timezone problem, possibly involving daylight saving time.
You are aware of the differences with these [types in PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html)?

```
timestamp
timestamp with time zone
```

Note the difference:

```
db=# SELECT '2011-10-20 10:00+1'::timestamp;                                                                                                                                                                  timestamp
---------------------
 2011-10-20 10:00:00


db=# SELECT '2011-10-20 10:00+1'::timestamp AT TIME ZONE '-1';
        timezone
------------------------
 2011-10-20 11:00:00+02
```

You may find a clue in the [chapter on time zones](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES).

---

Converting timestamp columns is simple. To just cut off the timezone part:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl ALTER col TYPE timestamp;
```

To convert all times to a specific timezone, for instance 'UTC':

```
ALTER TABLE tbl ALTER col TYPE timestamp USING col::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';
```

Comment: The problem is sometimes when I refresh the page it's an hour off and other times it's correct. Currently I am using the timestamp with time zone type.

Comment: Do you have need for `with time zone`? If not you could probably solve your problem by switching to just `timestamp`. Convert your table columns for that. I'll add some info to my answer.